# Django DateTimeField auto_now_add attribute is not working

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a `model` Alerte (below) that is updated in a function like this

```
Alerte.objects.create(
                asp_ale_loc = site,
                asp_ale_typ = 1, # activation de l'alerte
                # asp_ale_dat = timezone.now() -> replaced by auto_now_add
            )
```

I have modified asp_ale_dat format from `DateField` to `DateTimeField` and add `auto_now_add` as an attribute

I have run `makemigrations` and `migrate`

but when I create an Alerte object, `asp_ale_dat` is empty

and if I use `timezone.now()`, the only date is registered, not time...

```
class Alerte(models.Model):

    asp_ale_cle = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    asp_ale_loc = models.CharField("Site concerned by alert", max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    asp_ale_typ = models.IntegerField("Operation type on alert", null=True, blank=True,)
    asp_ale_dat = models.DateTimeField("Operation date on alert", null=True, blank=True,auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why that wouldn't work, and indeed I'm unable to reproduce this:

```
$ pip install django
Successfully installed asgiref-3.2.3 django-3.0.3 pytz-2019.3 sqlparse-0.3.0
$ django-admin startproject so60281850 .
$ subl so60281850/settings.py  # add so60281850 to INSTALLED_APPS
$ subl so60281850/models.py  # add in the model definition
$ python manage.py makemigrations so60281850
Migrations for 'so60281850':
  so60281850/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Alerte
$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, so60281850
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from so60281850.models import Alerte
>>> a = Alerte.objects.create(asp_ale_loc='foo', asp_ale_typ=1)
>>> a.asp_ale_dat
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 18, 13, 28, 49, 420520, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>>
$
```

Comment: SORRYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY... I just forgot to restart my shell....